# Select id within class CSS

Tags: html, css

I have been playing around with this code pen that I found: http://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/pLDwe

If I wrap the checkbox inside of a div with class "mynav," it no longer works. How can I apply the following formatting to the checkbox if it was wrapped inside of a div with class "mynav" ?

```
#toggle:checked ~ .message {
  top: 0;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .container {
  margin-top: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not possible with css only. The "checkbox hack" method that you are using needs the elements to be next siblings of the checkbox in order to be targeted from general sibling selector `~`.

The only solution if you have to keep your new markup is to use javascript.